# Customer is unhappy about my progress

Tags: new-job, contractors

**Background:**
I have been deployed to a customer that has got a massive testing framework in place; in order to properly meet their expectation, I need to spend some time on learning their framework as well as a new programming language.

- I can not spend more than 8 hours in this customer's office
- It is no point to download their framework and study it in my own time as I can not execute them outside this customer's office.
- I have been with this customer for a week and they feel I am not making much progress. To be honest, they are right.
- My contract here is 3 month (60 working days more or less) in total and I have spent 8 working days in their office.

What should I do from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should I do from here?

When I need to do work stuff at home (careful with that) I use **remote desktop, telnet, ssh, etc.** That way I can access local resources when physically being elsewhere.

Just be sure you get clearance to use such tools.

Also, if you are learning a *framework* on some *language* you can surely study both of them on your free time (via any agnostic online resource, like Stack Overflow), unless they were company developed. In that case they must surely have it documented for you to learn it.

If nothing else works, consider "sacrificing" a couple extra hours on their premises learning and obtaining the information you need to learn this on your own as fast as possible, so you can then perform normally on your tasks.

Comment: Would that help if I go to my customers and tell them I need time to learn? I know I may sound like an idiot by doing it, but be honestly up front may help?

Comment: @YuZhang, customers usually pay you not to learn, but to do something for them.

Comment: @L.Dutch, I will not mention learning process then; I will request VPN access for remote access, this way, I can do my learning outside of the normal office hours.

Comment: @YuZhang Mr. Dutch is right in a way. first get vpn access or similar. Then try to learn with that resource. Then if it doesn't work talk to your manager about how to proceed, or rightfully say you *now* need some help, but not without trying first with this new option.

Comment: @DarkCygnus, thank you very much. I will proceed as you suggested.

Comment: Glad it helped @YuZhang :) consider waiting to hear any other answer users may give (or seeing others back up this answer) so you get a stronger course of action. Good luck

Answer (score 9):

> I have been with this customer for a week and they feel I am not
>   making much progress. To be honest, they are right.
>
> My contract here is 3 month (60 working days more or less) in total
>   and I have spent 8 working days in their office.
>
> What should I do from here?

You should talk to your boss.

You should indicate that both the customer and you agree that you are making insufficient progress. Your boss may have suggestions about how to cut your learning curve short - perhaps through help from another worker in your company, perhaps through some learning materials.

Your boss may offer to have the time you spent on learning be free of charge to the customer.

But if you conclude that after already spending a significant chunk of time on the problem already it won't get significantly better soon, you should indicate that perhaps someone else should be assigned to this project - someone who won't take up so many hours *learning* and can make more progress *doing* more quickly.

Then you can be assigned to a project that more closely suits your skills.

Clients usually want a contractor to come in and start productive work very quickly, if not right away. They don't want to pay for a protracted learning curve. If you can't meet the customer's needs, either you or the customer needs to initiate a change. It may be better if it comes from you.

Answer (score 3):

Good answers already, but they miss the core problem.

You have been deployed to a customer without the knowledge and experience to do the actual job. This is a failing on the part of your company and is going to reflect badly on everyone concerned. So this is where you address the problem, not the customer (they have already expressed disappointment and are uninterested in your dramas).

Your company needs to either deploy someone else instead of you, or send you some help. Either way it's bad company policy to let this get worse so talk to your boss and sort out a solution.

The best solution in my opinion is that another expert is deployed that knows the requisite language, works with you for a day or two getting up to speed and then takes over.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no one on site familiar with the framework they will likely judge the progress partly by your own level of confidence.  So always remain confident.

You should also look for ways to have small successes. Running an increasing number of tests etc. Usually when things have gone south on a project I was on, I looked back and realized that although there was much I did not understand there was lots of small things I could have done to show more progress. So don't confuse total understanding with showing progress which is what you need to do.

If there is a new language involved then of course it takes time to learn that new language. Try to manage expectations of the client.  Perhaps the client was lead to believe that you already knew the language or technology perhaps by whomever sent you out there? If so then declaring you don't now it is a bad idea!

I would avoid saying anything too flat like: I don't know the language at all. Or everything is new to me.  How you word things is important.  You might talk about the interface between the framework and what you are testing and needing to learn more about a particular aspect sounds better.

Managing expectations is crucial and I would focus on that to give yourself more time. I would not explicitly say I don't know this language or technology. A lot depends on if there is anyone else besides yourself on site who knows the technology. Is there? Also how did you get the project? Why was it assigned to you in the first place? If you are confident you can make reasonable progress in the future and just need more time than keep it.

Otherwise its time to start thinking about transitioning to a new project. Depends on if you are contractor or salaried. If w2 or salaried you will get paid for all time spent on the client site but otherwise might not.  Is your goal to make it last as long as possible or actually succeed at the project? What are your chances of success and how long do you think it would take? These estimates need to be made to decide what to do next.

You also might want to start immediately sending out resumes or seeking reassignment depending on the situation. You probably should NOT inform the client of this however until you have made up your mind one way or the other. Please tell us more about your situation and client. Is it your own client? how did you end up with the project. We can better help you much better if you provide this basic information about how you ended up at client site.

Comment: please edit this so it isn't a wall of text.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep just did, more readable now